# Imap proxy with message cache

Tags: reverse-proxy, imapsync, imap

Does an imap proxy with full message list and message body caching exist?

I see two possible variations, one with on-demand caching (user clicks on a mailbox and a message list is fetched from "master" and cached for next click from another mail client / webmail connected to the proxy. Same for clicking on a message with message body cache). Another variation is auto-fetch, some kind of script or daemon that fetches messages on background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the first variation (fetch on demand) have a look at the dovecot imapc backend:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/ImapcProxy

Comment: Thank you, is there something for the second variation?

Comment: there are a lot of scripts/daemons that download mail in the background which you could easily serve again with a local dovecot installation, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/ , http://fetchmail.berlios.de/